# Oder of my json request is getting sorted in alphabetical order when i am getting data from data file.i dnt want my json request to get sorted

Tags: json, postman

```
{
   "ID":0,
   "OrganizationId":"",
   "OrganizationName":"",
   "Name":"",
   "IsActive":"True",
   "Type":2,
   "AppliesTo":1,
   "TagHOD":"",
   "DisplayAsPrimary":"false",
   "Values":[

   ]
}
```

Above is  my json request which I have stored in a data file

Below is my json request body which I am getting after sending a parameter into it. It is sorted into alphabetical order which I don't want. I want the same order as above eg ID Should be first then OrganizationId

```
{
    "AppliesTo": 1,
    "DisplayAsPrimary": "false",
    "ID": 0,
    "IsActive": "True",
    "Name": "TAG1205510333275",
    "OrganizationId": 2404,
    "OrganizationName": "",
    "TagHOD": "",
    "Type": 2,
    "Values": [
        {
            "HODEmail": "tagsapiautomationae@mailinator.com",
            "Id": 1,
            "IsDeleted": false,
            "Text": "Level20"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What's the actual problem here? Are you seeing this behaviour in Postman? Are you see a specific error as a result of the reordering? You might need to expand on the details to explain the question more.

Comment: I am getting incorrect response . i don't want my request body to get sort in alphabetical order

Comment: Response from where? The endpoint you're hitting? Is this something that you own or is it a 3rd party API?

Comment: its not actually in order - its just a dictionary. whatever parser you are using is sorting it for you. if you want to preserve order, return an array

Answer (score 1):

The JSON specification states: "[An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs.](https://www.json.org/json-en.html)"

When working with JSON (and objects in most languages), the properties in objects are inherently unordered. You can't rely on different systems giving you the properties in the same order you supply them. In fact, you can't even rely on a single system giving you the properties in the same order all the time within a given execution of the code, even though many systems do behave that way.

If you want to preserve ordering, you either need to use an array to store the data, or you can use an array of object property names that stores the keys in the order you want, so you can use that array to reference them in the desired order later.

EG:

```
   keyorder = ["ID",
               "OrganizationId",
               "OrganizationName",
               "Name",
               "IsActive",
               "Type",
               "AppliesTo",
               "TagHOD",
               "DisplayAsPrimary",
               "Values"
               ]
```

You can then loop over this array when accessing elements in your object, so you are always accessing them in your defined order.

In python, with an object named "data" this would look like:

```
 for key in keyorder:
      print data.get(key)
```