# Email Sender sends in a random order

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, for-in-loop

After filling out a form the script sends an email but in a random order that does not make sense at all.  When I try to manipulate the code I get errors and the script stops working.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var values = e.namedValues;
  var htmlBody = '<ol>';
  for (Key in values) {
    var label = Key;
    var data = values[Key];
    htmlBody += '<li>' + label + ": " + data + '</li>';
  };
  htmlBody += '</ol>';
  MailApp.sendEmail('email@email.com','WORK REQUEST: ATTENTION NEEDED', '', {htmlBody:htmlBody})
}
```

Comment: The data you are looping over in `for (Key in values)` is a javascript object, these are inherently un-ordered. There is no guarantee that the keys will be returned in the same order any two times you loop over them. Although this question speaks about JSON, the underlying issue is the same & solution is the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62306963/oder-of-my-json-request-is-getting-sorted-in-alphabetical-order-when-i-am-gettin/62309081#62309081

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `e.namedValues` use `e.values` together with reading the form response sheet columns headers

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  var headersRange = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,e.values.length);
  var headers = headersRange.getValues()[0];
  var htmlBody = '<ol>';
  for (var i = 0; i < e.values.length; i++) {
    htmlBody += '<li>' + headers[i] + ": " + e.values[i] + '</li>';
  };
  htmlBody += '</ol>';
  MailApp.sendEmail('email@email.com','WORK REQUEST: ATTENTION NEEDED', '', {htmlBody:htmlBody})
}
```

Why?

1. `e.namedValues` returns and object. Object properties are unordered.
2. By default, the columns order is the same as the questions order